# Get scroll position of HTML element relative to visible portion of container

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a web page with:

1. A fixed header at the top of varying size, covering up the page's main content.
2. A page with a deeply nested scroll container.
3. Within that container, several other deeply nested elements.

What I want to do is scroll that container so that one of the elements inside lines up with the top of the *visible* portion of the container. **I believe what I am looking for is the top of the nested element relative to the top of the visible portion of the container.**

Unfortunately I cannot use `.offsetTop` because that only references an element's immediate parent, and due to the structure of the page these elements are too deeply nested for that to be of any use. It's always a fixed number. Same with the scroll container; its immediate parent is not the window. Frustratingly, the header is not of a fixed height, so I can't hardcode it into my calculations very easily. I also cannot use jQuery.

I tried using `getBoundingClientRect` for both the element and the container, but they are always a fixed distance away from each other and it doesn't give me the information I need about how far the element is scrolled relative to the container's visible area, unfortunately.

EDIT: We have a scrolling solution in place already, but we were hoping to improve it through a certain proposed means that I am trying to determine the feasibility of. I would like to ask that everyone please try to only answer the question in bold, rather than proposing alternate solutions. I really do appreciate any help on offer, but I am hoping to get some extremely specific information based on an extremely specific scenario.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: dose the element you want to scroll upto have a id?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee The element has a unique class name. I can easily obtain both the element object and the container element object.

Comment: @Dekel try this: https://jsfiddle.net/xnht5y0e/5/ JSFiddle is being extremely finicky for me right now and won't recognize a function that's right there, hence the script in the footer.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense you want the parent to be scrolled or the child (the actual blue box)?

Comment: @Dekel I want the blue box to be scrolled to just underneath the header, which is not guaranteed to always be 64px. I've updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense are you looking for something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/8udzja91/ ?

Comment: Note that I added a red border around the header to show the position of the blue box when scrolled....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152874/discussion-between-thesounddefense-and-dekel).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this kind of issue earlier, you can try this to auto scroll to the element

```
var elem = <some select operation that returns the element>;
elem.id = <some temp id> //if no id is there
var a  = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "#" + elem.id;
a.click();
```

If you wish, you can remove the id from your element once its done.

Comment: Will this bring `elem` to the top of the page, where it will be partly covered by the header, or will it place the `elem` just under the header?

Comment: well, hopefully to the top of the page.. just give it a try.

Comment: Well I'm not having any problem scrolling the element. My problem is getting it to scroll to that really specific point.